# Chrome detecting ads on site without ads

Tags: google-chrome, download, ads

Google Chrome says it is blocking ads on our web application, but our application does not have any ads in it. This is a SAAS application and includes regular downloading of data files.

The Chrome dev console says: "Chrome is blocking ads on this site because this site tends to show ads that interrupt, distract, mislead, or prevent user control. You should fix the issues as soon as possible and submit your site for another review."

Our application has also been marked by Google as being Deceptive for this reason.

Google's resources for resolving the problem are very unhelpful. All they say is to remove intrusive ads, but not what ads we are displaying in particular.

Any knowledge of this problem and possible solutions? Maybe some bad practices to avoid?

Comment: It would be great if you could post the source code of the website or the link to the website if you want better help.

Comment: Here is a link to an example site: https://demo.feedallocationsystem.com/

Comment: [Stack of your website](https://shorturl.at/zGIRX) Wappalyzer didn't pick up anything, I don't know.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm currently facing the same problem, with no idea how to fix it

Comment: We have not found a solution

Comment: TBH the only real long-term solution probably involves preventing the same company from having both a browser monopoly and advertising dominance at the same time. If you have `iframes`, Chrome seems to identify them as ads if they're not from the same domain/origin.